# How to solve null pointer exception when passing attributes between servlet class and jsp.file

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, attributes

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` error when I run `userList.jsp`:

I am trying to output the size of an array list of User objects:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : userList
    Created on : 13-Mar-2019, 22:08:54
    Author     : sonia
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.mycompany.gartisweb.domain.User"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% ArrayList users = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("users"); %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>List of Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>

                <% users.size(); %>

    </body>
</html>
```

This what my servlet class looks like:

```
public class UserListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public UserListServlet() {
    }

    //private final UserDao ud = new UserDao();

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

       // List<User> users = new ArrayList();
         //   users = ud.findAllUsers();


        request.setAttribute("users", new UserDao().findAllUsers());
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("userList.jsp");
        //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("userList.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        //rd.forward(request, response);

    }
```

The findAllUsers() in UserDao class:

```
 @Override
public ArrayList<User> findAllUsers() {
    ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection con;
    con = DBConnection.createConnection();
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = con.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");
        while (rs.next()) {
           User user = new User();

            user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString(2));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString(3));
            user.setFirstName(rs.getString(4));
            user.setSurName(rs.getString(5));
            user.setRole(rs.getString(6));
            userList.add(user);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {

        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);

            }
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);

            }
        }
    }

    return userList;
}
```

I can't find the error in my code, could anyone explain to me how I could resolve this issue ?

Comment: Keep the whole code if `service` method within a try and it's catch with Exception and inside catch you print the stack trace, which will show the line number on which exception occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are accessing the JSP directly with `http://.../userList.jsp` URL. Use the URL which is mapped to `UserListServlet` so the servlet can set the variable and do the forward.

You also probably want to do `<%= users.size(); %>` to display the users count.

Comment: Ok i have done this, but now  the size of the arraylist still does not display ( see screenshot above) ...

Comment: @SoniaMathews instead of `<%` use `<%=` as suggested in the answer.